# convert date into string in json bootstrap calendar

Tags: php, json, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, strtotime

i have an issue in using bootstrap calendar. the example of event.json.php give me a code like this : `"id": "293",
            "title": "This is warning class event with very long title to check how it fits to evet in day view",
            "url": "http://www.example.com/",
            "class": "event-warning",
            "start": "1362938400000",
            "end":   "1363197686300"`
and i try to convert the "start" into date. the result is not the same with example. then, i try to give a date string from the database, but it's not work. so, when i try to convert 1363197686300 into date, the result is not like im thinking. can anyone help me to solve this issue?
please feel free to ask me if you confuse with my english. T_T :)

here are my code. i just reuse the sample of events.json.php i just loop the code and pull the value from database.

```
{
"success": 1,
"result": [
<?php include "config\conn.php";
                    $no = 1;
                    $sql="SELECT * from tbl_thread";
                    $query = mysql_query($sql);
                    $jmlh_evnt = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        if($no == $jmlh_evnt){
    echo '{
        "id": "'.$row['id_thread'].'",
        "title": "'.$row['judul'].'",
        "url": "http://www.example.com/",
        "class": "'.$row['status'].'",
        "start": "'.date("Y/m/d H:i:s", $row['tgl_event']).'",
        "end":   "'.date("Y/m/d H:i:s", $row['selesai_event']).'"
        }'; }
    else {
    echo '{
        "id": "'.$row['id_thread'].'",
        "title": "'.$row['judul'].'",
        "url": "http://www.example.com/",
        "class": "'.$row['status'].'",
        "start": "'.date("Y/m/d H:i:s", $row['tgl_event']).'",
        "end":   "'.date("Y/m/d H:i:s", $row['selesai_event']).'"
    },';

    }

}$no++; ?>
    {
        "id": "",
        "title": "",
        "url": "",
        "class": "",
        "start": "2015-11-14 12:00:00",
        "end":   "2015-11-15 12:00:00"
    }
]
```

}

> { "success": 1, "result": [ { "id": "1", "title": "Gala Dinner with Rektor", "url": "http://www.example.com/", "class": "event-info", "start": "2015/10/11 12:00:00", "end": "2015/10/12 12:00:00" },{ "id": "2", "title": "test", "url": "http://www.example.com/", "class": "event-warning", "start": "2015/11/12 00:00:00", "end": "2015/11/12 00:00:00" }, { "id": "", "title": "", "url": "", "class": "", "start": "2015-11-14 12:00:00", "end": "2015-11-15 12:00:00" } ] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the number from the string, and pass it into the Date constructor:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(start));
```

And then you can format the date

```
var newDate = dateFormat(date, "mm/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: i already did, sir. but it's still not work. by the way, i post the date into database in string format. so i think it would be the easy way to fill the start and end property in event.json.php

Comment: Can you show you code a bit so that we can see where the problem is.

Comment: Will this help by replacing `$row['tgl_event']` with `date('Y/m/d H:i:s' ,$row['tgl_event'])`

Comment: sir, i thank you for your help. but it's still not work. in the calendar still not display the event that recorded in my database. oh God, it makes me (^&*^%*^$&*& :D

Comment: `strtotime($row['tgl_event'])` use this in place of `date('Y/m/d H:i:s' ,$row['tgl_event'])` and can you tell me in which format is the date in your database? or can you provide a sample output of your date from database?

Comment: in my database, the date using string. example : tgl_event : 1444557600.

Comment: and here the output of events.json.php : see above

Comment: Try adding zero's like this `strtotime($row['tgl_event']).'000`